# Getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined " error

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am getting the "Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined".

However, the "form is defined in an object. I am not going to post the entire JS code just where the form is declared.

```
line 6- const elements = 
line 7- {
line 8-     form: document.querySelector("#new-task-form"),
line 9-     input: document.querySelector("#new-task-input"),
line 10-    list: document.querySelector("#tasks"),
line 11-    cal:document.querySelector("#calendar")
line 12- }

line 91- const submitHandler = (event) =>{
line 92-    event.preventDefault();
line 93-    createTask();
line 94- }

line 96 - form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);
```

The `form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);` is calling back the function of `submitHandler`. So not sure why it is giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

```
const createTask = () => {
    const id = createId()
    const task = elements.input.value;
    const date = elements.cal.value;

    if(!task && !date) return alert("Please fill in task and select date");
    if(!task) return alert("Please fill in task");
    if(!date) return alert("Please select date");

    const tasks = document.createElement("div");

    tasks.innerHTML = `
    <div class="task" date-id = "${id}">
        <div class="content">
            <input type ="checkbox" class="tick">
            <input class = text id = "text" readonly>
            <label class = "due-date" for ="text">${date}</label>
        </div>

        <div class = "action">
            <button class="edit" data-id="${id}>Edit</button>
            <button class="delete" data-id="${id}>Delet</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
    elements.list.appendChild(tasks)
    return task
}
```

The issue was that `const task = elements.input.value`, was defined incorrectly, i had it as `const task = input.value`